# async ajax call for multiple image urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

This if for an ASP.NET Core application which displays pictures taken from a car -remote images on a server-. The pictures are the one the user sees (Car.$image) + 12 images in a buffer for a smooth navigation. 
The frontend uses Javascript and to update the pictures, it calls Get method in ImageUrlController which answer is image url matching the current position.

Being not familiar with async/await and in spite of many attempts, this code doesn't work:

`Car.updateImage = function(){

   Car.$image.attr("src", getImageUrl());
}`

```
async function getImageUrl() {

var APIModel = {
    "position": Car.state.position,
    "km": Car.state.km
};
var result = await $.ajax({
    url: "/ImageUrlController/Get",
    dataType: "text",
    data: { "jsonData": JSON.stringify(APIModel) },
    type: 'GET'
});

return result;
```

}

In debug I get the result of the async call but it's not set to the src.
I know I could do it in a .success() of the call, but again I have 12 pictures to continuously update, so I need the results to be directly "injected" to the src of the 12 pictures.

How should I write this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most elegant way to write it, but it seems to work:

```
(async function () {
    Car.$image.attr("src", await getImageUrl());
})();
```